# Seating Problem Formula Derivation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am trying to solve this problem, but I am just confused on how to approach it.

> Problem Statement: A class should consist of N students. Inside the
> class the students have to be seated in a row of N chairs. In the
> class of N students, only fewer than B boys can sit together and fewer
> than G girls can be seated together. In how many different ways can a
> class of N students be formed? (Assume that you have more than N boys
> and N girls available).

This is not a homework question, but a question from one of the exercises that I am trying to solve from a book (self-learning). I am able to solve questions where the variable are known (this is from advance section where variables are unknown and we should derive formulas). It would be grateful if someone could explain how to approach such problems (or at least point me to some resource for such problems). Also I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to solve this particular problem as well.

Thank You.

**Denise**

Answer (score 0):

This solution is taking the assumption that it has to be in algebric form rather than be able to give an actual absolute value.

So taking first condition means that for the problem you can assume that all the students are in one long line (rather than a typical classroom)

The second condition means that you can only have limited number of the same gender students next to each other (eg you can't have a class of just boys or girls)

The last statement just means that there are essentially unlimited 'resources' so any combination of boys and girls is possible.

So using the last statement you can work out the absolute maximum number of combinations will be 2^N as each place has 2 possibilties as each thing is independent of the other hence using num of possibilites to the power of number of spaces.

As said the second condition means you can only have a limited amount of boys and girls next to eachother. Meaning that it is a divisor of the maximum of 2^N.

I sincerely apologies but this is as much as I think I can give without risking making something up creating a false answer and leading you down wrong path but I believe what I have given you is a good way to help breakdown the question to help understand constriants and is most likely a good way for you to attempt any similar questions.